# Does AngularJS routing require AJAX to execute?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I see that angular routing will add a `#` hash sign to the UR. Does that mean that it doesn't need to communicate to the server via AJAX to pull up an HTML template. Or, does it still need an AJAX request?

Comment: Any feedback or suggestions?

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for laying this out so comprehensively!

Comment: Nice :) You may going to mark it as the right answer? It would help other users and thats how Stackoverflow works.

Comment: I see you asked 3 other questions without marking an answer as right. You should do that. Think about the user who try to help ya. They spend a lot of time to help you with your problems. Think about the time you save while other spend time to help ya. Give them the "tick" or upvotes is the minimum you should invest.

Comment: Thanks I never knew to do that. I will do that on all my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you implement AngularJS it will use `xhr` to load resources asynchronously. This happends for example while loading template files. But you dont need to split you views into files, so a AJAX requests will not be fired. You could also use `$templateCache` where all your templates will be stored inline at application start.

#### Define template inline, will not fire a AJAX request:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="my-template-name">
    Content of the template.
</script>
```

#### Load a template by [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) source path will fire a AJAX request:

```
<div ng-include src="'aTemplateFile.html'"></div>
```

#### Define templates inline and include it with `ng-include` will not fire a AJAX request:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="my-inline-template">
    Content of the template.
</script>
<div ng-include src="'my-inline-template'"></div>
```

#### Using the `$routeProvider` with template URLs will fire a AJAX request

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl : "main.html"
        });
});
```

#### Using the `$routeProvider` with inline template define will not fire a AJAX request

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            template : "<h1>Main</h1><p>Click on the links to change this content</p>"
        })
});
```

#### Using inline filling of `$templateCache` will not fire a AJAX request:

```
$templateCache.put('templateId.html', 'This is the content of the template');
```

#### Using the `$http` provider will fire AJAX request for sure.

```
$http.get('http://example.com');
```